# Leica Q2M JPG files cannot be read by any of my Ubuntu (21.10) image software

Tags: jpeg, gimp, linux, leica

I very recently picked up a Leica Q2M, and on my first attempt to read JPG files recorded on its storage media I've found that nothing on my Ubuntu 21.10 installation can read the files. I've tried `geeqie`, `ristretto`, `gimp`, the browsers, and a couple of other things, and none of them can read the files.

The common thread is an error: `Unsupported marker type 0x66`

Is there something I don't know that I need to do in order to support these files? Shouldn't they be plain JPG files?

*edit* this appears to be a weirdness with particular SD cards, still working it out.

*edit* — OK I think this was a hardware/firmware problem with the antique laptop I'm using. External SD (USB) readers work fine.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is with the computer hardware, not the camera or image files.

Answer (score 3):

I've concluded that this is a hardware issue. An external USB card reader works properly; there's nothing wrong or unusual about the files involved.

The machine is a fairly old (2013) Dell Inspiron 15" laptop (model 3521), in case anybody else notices a similar problem.